# CSS/Sass setting background-color with opacity 0.5 over a background image

Tags: css, sass, background-image, background-color

Currently I have a dark background image like this:

[image]

So now if I write text on it, it is not that clearly visible. I want to put a background color or layer over the image and set its `opacity` to `.5` so that I get a more blackish background.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Any reason not to just edit the image in Photoshop?

Comment: I don't know photoshop.

Comment: Well, I meant any image editor. [Paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/) or [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) if you need something free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using an overlay: http://jsfiddle.net/q2m5x/1/

Just put `<div class="overlay"></div>` right after your body (or whatever container has the background image).

Comment: the background images it to the body tag

Comment: @Mrudul_T Alright, so put that little bit of HTML right after the opening `<body>`, then include the CSS. Make sure you edit the overlay dimensions to fit your page. Also you can play around with the opacity  to find what looks best.

Comment: also how do I fit my 1900x800px background image to 1200px and auto height body. currently only one fourth of the images is shown

Comment: @Mrudul_T I'm using Chrome so you're good there, but Chrome's not the one you'll have to worry about. As far as I know that overlay method will work in all browsers. To size down the image, you COULD use some CSS, but it's better practice to just resize the image using some editing program. Make sure to keep your 19:8 ratio when resizing. To have a minimum height, you can also use CSS. Just add `min-height: 400px;` replacing 400 with whatever height you'd like. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-height/